# How to pass a local variable to another function?

Tags: c, function, variables

So I am doing a text adventure game. It has Hundreds of lines of story, a fully functioning combat system, and I am now trying to create an influence system. Basically it is supposed to work like this: Certain responses/actions will increase or decrease your influence over different characters. I want to use the influence variable in choice_6() and story_7(). How do I do that? Please do not send me any links. I've gone through many many other answers and they haven't made sense to me so if your going to copy and paste, at least explain it a different way than other answers. Thank you.

```
int choice_6()
    {
        int influence = 0;
        int choice = 0;
        printf("What do you do?\n");
        printf("\t1. You: No. I know absolutely nothing about you. You could be a monster\n");
        printf("\ttoo for all I know! Normal people don't turn into frogs!\n");
        printf("\t2. You: Your right we should keep moving. You can tell me when your\n");
        printf("\tready.\n");
        printf("\t3. You: Okay where do you think should we go then?\n");
        do 
        {
            scanf_s("%i", &choice);
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        printf("\tBrie flashes a pained look on her face and you immediately regret saying that.\n");
                        printf("\tBrie: You really think I'm a monster?\n");
                        system("pause");
                        influence -= 10;
                        printf("You lose influence and are now at %i with Brie.\n", influence);
                        system("pause");
                        printf("Influence affects characters reactions towards you, their combat effectiveness, and even their allegiances in rare cases.\n");
                        printf("However, depending on the situation, low influence is not always a bad thing...\n");
                        system("pause");
                        printf("\tYou: Your right we should keep moving.\n");
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        printf("\tBrie: Thank you. I'd rather not discuss this my life story in a dark\n");
                        printf("\tdungeon.\n");
                        system("pause");
                        influence += 10;
                        printf("You gain influence and are now at %i influence with Brie.\n", influence);
                        system("pause");
                        printf("Influence affects characters reactions towards you, their combat effectiveness, and even their allegiances in rare cases.\n");
                        printf("However, depending on the situation, low influence is not always a bad thing...\n");
                        system("pause");
                        printf("\tYou: I'd have to agree with you there. Let's see what is up these stairs.\n");
                        choice = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        printf("Brie smiles at this.\n");
                        printf("\tBrie: Well the only way out seems to be these stairs so let's go up.\n");
                        system("pause");
                        influence += 10;
                        printf("You gain influence and are now at %i influence with Brie.\n", influence);
                        system("pause");
                        printf("Influence affects characters reactions towards you, their effectiveness in combat, and even their allegiances in rare cases.\n");
                        printf("However, depending on the situation, low influence is not always a bad thing...\n");
                        system("pause");
                        printf("\tYou: Sounds good to me I am quite frankly done with dungeons about now.\n");
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        printf("Type the number for the choice you want to do\n");
                        system("pause");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }while(choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3);
    }

    int story_7()
    {
        printf("\ninfluence is %i\n", influence);
        printf("You lead the way walking upstairs\n");
        system("pause");
        printf("You turn the corner while crouched to find a room full of gremlins and goblins.\n");
        system("pause");
        printf("You grab Brie's hand and roll to the left behind some crates before they see you.\n");
        system("pause");
        printf("Even though you realize you will probably not make it out of this situation\n");
        printf("alive, you can't help but feel lucky with Brie being so tightly pressed against you on the floor.\n");
        system("pause");
        printf("After a long period of silence to confirm nobody has seen you both enter,\n");
        printf("Brie looks up at you and rolls her eyes.\n");
        system("pause");
        printf("*whispers*\tBrie: At least buy me dinner first jeez.\n");
        system("pause");
        printf("*whispers*\tYou: I'd love to but we should probably kill these uglies first.\n");
        system("pause");
        if (influence > 0)
        {
            printf("Brie laughs at this and slowly leans you off her to have both of you crouch.");
            system("pause");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Brie: Ugh just get off of me!\n");
            printf("Brie pushes you off her violently and you manage to stay crouched.");
            system("pause");
        }
    }



    int main()
{
    int play = 0;
    int influence = 0;
    intro_1();
    story_1();
    choice_1();
    story_2();
    choice_2();
    story_3();
    choice_3();
    story_4();
    choice_4();
    story_5();
    choice_5();
    intro_2();
    combat_1();
    story_6();
    choice_6();
    story_7();
    choice_7();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: How do you think your `scanf_s("%i", &choice)` call modifies a variable local to `choice_6()`?

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't think it does. The integer "choice" is a variable I use for the player to choose which case they want to do.

Comment: @user2073308: Uh, if you don't think your `scanf_s` call modifies the value `choice`, then how on earth do you think it works?

Comment: @jamesdlin ok maybe I wasn't clear. "choice6()" is the function name for the sixth choice you make in the game. In that function, scanf_s modifies the value of "choice" and using a switch it determines what case to use based on the value of "choice".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a *pointer* to the `influence` variable, if you want to modify it from within a function. Like this:

```
int choice_6(int *influence)
{
    // ...
    *influence -= 10;
    // use *influence wherever you would have had used influence before
    // ...
}

int story_7(int influence)
{
    // ...
    if (influence > 0) ...
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    int influence = 0;
    // ...
    choice_6(&influence);
    story_7(influence);
    // ...
}
```

This is passing a *pointer* to `choice_6()` because you need to modify `influence` from within that function. This is passing the *value* to `story_7()` because you do not need to modify the `influence` value there.

Comment: When I was talking to my programming teacher about the game I was making, the one thing he said was: "Pointers and Go-To's are bad programming." So are there any other solutions you can come up with that does not use those two concepts?

Comment: @user2073308: if your teacher said that about pointers, s/he really shouldn't get anywhere near C. While pointers have its gotchas for beginners, you won't get very far programming in C without pointers. Careful use of pointers is essential in any non-trivial C program. If you want to avoid pointers, then don't use C; there are other languages that doesn't have pointers at all (e.g. Python, Java) or where pointers are often not necessary for good programming (e.g. C++). C is not such a language.

Comment: @LieRyan I don't know why I said pointers I meant globals I apologize and your correct that pointers are necessary for C. I was just frustrated I couldn't get this to work.

Anyways, your solution did actually work so thank you very much!!!! :DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Answer (score 1):

You should create game object(s) that stores the state of the game, in this case, influence and other event flags.

You will then need to either set this game object as a global, or pass it around by pointer/reference to every functions that may need to check or modify the game state.

```
struct MyGame {
    int influence;
    int has_cheese;
};

void choice_6(struct MyGame * game) {
    ...
    game->influence += 10;
    ...
}
int main(...) {
    struct MyGame game;
    game->influence = 0;
    game->has_cheese = FALSE; // or 0
    ...
    choice_6(&game);
    ....
}
```

Comment: FALSE is undefined, it gives me an error redefintion of formal parameter game when I do  choice_6(&game);
and  story_7(&game);

Comment: @user2073308: That is only an example code, you should modify it to fit your purpose instead of copying blindly.  You can use 0 instead of FALSE if you don't have it #define-ed. Secondly, you can enter the error message you received (i.e. redefinition of formal parameter) on a search engine (e.g. Google) and the reason for the error should become fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `influence` variable by reference. This means the function(s) you give the reference to can change the value of the variable itself (not just a copy of the variable).

Do this by prepending the parameter with a `*` in the function signatures, and passing with a `&` prepended:

```
int choice_6(int *influence)
    {
....

    int main()
{
    int play = 0;
    int influence = 0;
    choice_6(&influence);
....
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I keep getting errors when I try to call influence in story_7

Comment: every function you want to modify the variable `influence` needs to have the variable's reference (pointer) passed to it, so just as you need to change the function `int choice_6()` to `int choice_6(int *influence)`, you must also change `int story_7()` to `int story_7(int *influence)`